# Scope is not recognizing both columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-tokeninput

On my Tokeninput autocomplete field I am trying to make the returned columns be both my `:address` and `:website` when it goes by the defined `:store` method.

```
class BusinessStore < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :search_by_store, lambda { |q|
       (q ? where(["address LIKE ? or website LIKE ? like ?", '%'+ q + '%', '%'+ q + '%','%'+ q + '%' ])  : {})}

    def store
        if self.online_store
          "#{business_name} - #{website}"
        else
          "#{business_name} - #{address}"
        end
    end
end

class BusinessStoresController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @business_stores = BusinessStore.all
    @business_stores = BusinessStore.search_by_store(params[:q])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @business_stores }
      format.json { render :json => @business_stores.collect{|b|{:id => b.id, :name => b.store } } }
    end
  end
end
```

My json page : `http://localhost:3000/business_stores.json` shows all the results correctly but the Token field only shows `:address` results and not website ones. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(q ? where(["address LIKE ? OR website LIKE ?", "%#{q}%", "%#{q}%" ]) : {})}
```